# How to make nested async requests in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

inside main.js:

```
$.when(
    $.get('foo/bar.html'),
    $.get('lorem/ipsum.html')
).done(function(data1, data2){
     someCode();
});
```

inside lorem/ipsum.html:

```
$.when(
    $.get('otherStuff.html'),
    $.get('example.html')
).done(function(data1, data2){
     moreCode();
});
```

How can I make `someCode()` run after `moreCode()`?

Comment: `In $.get(otherUrl) there is another $.when().done()` ... no there isn't, not in the code you've shown at least

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
$.when( $.ajax( url ), $.ajax( otherUrl ) )
 .then( myFunc, myFailure );

function myFunc(){
   //get called on success.
}

function myFailure (){
   //get called, if either one has an error.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the then() https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

> In the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to
>   jQuery.when(), the method returns the Promise from a new "master"
>   Deferred object that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds
>   it has been passed. The method will resolve its master Deferred as
>   soon as all the Deferreds resolve, or reject the master Deferred as
>   soon as one of the Deferreds is rejected. If the master Deferred is
>   resolved, the doneCallbacks for the master Deferred are executed. The
>   arguments passed to the doneCallbacks provide the resolved values for
>   each of the Deferreds, and matches the order the Deferreds were passed
>   to jQuery.when().

```
$.when(
    $.get(url),
    $.get(otherUrl)
).then(function(data1){
     someCode();
});
```

Comment: what's the difference between jQuery promises `.then` and `.done` methods?

Comment: the only difference is, `.then` takes `onResolved`, `onFailure` and `onProgress` callbacks, whereas `.done` only takes `onResolved` ... therefore it seems that `.done(fn)` is equivalent to `.then(fn)` (with respect to the code in the question)- so, should *make no difference* to the OP's code

Answer (score 0):

I think your code work just fine.

You can try to make invalid url `https://XXjsonplaceholder.typicode.com` and `someCode` will not be hit

```js
var url1 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1";
var url2 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2";

/* 
$.get(url1).done(function (result1) {
 console.log(result1);
});
*/

$.when(
  $.get(url1),
  $.get(url2)
).then(function(result1, result2) {
  console.log("result1");
  console.log(result1[0]);

  console.log("result2");
  console.log(result2[0]);

  someCode();
});

function someCode() {
  console.log("someCode here");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```